# Best way to make a complex Kibana Metric ( filter out buckets value on a condition then count the remaining values in tha bucket )

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aggregation, metrics, vega

I stumbled across an issue I cannot resolve and I have no idea how to continue from here.

My initial situation is simple :
I have logs of 'problems' every minute in this format : ID|Status.
Open logs continue to send log every minute to say they are still open.
When a problem is 'closed' it sends a last log with the status close and stop sending logs.

So for example :
(now - 3 minutes) I have 3 document : id1|open / id2|open / id3|open

(now - 2 minutes) I have 6 document : id1|open / id2|open / id3|open /// id1|close / id2|open / id3|open

(now - 1 minute) I have 8 document : id1|open / id2|open / id3|open /// id1|close / id2|open / id3|open /// id2|open / id3|close

(now) I have 9 document : id1|open / id2|open / id3|open /// id1|close / id2|open / id3|open /// id2|open / id3|close /// id2|open

What I want :

1. A table that shows only OPEN problems
2. A metric that shows the number of OPEN problems

In both case I want to gather at (now) the number of open problems ( Problems that have never been closed )
So at n-3 I have 3 open problems / n-2 I have 2 open problems / n-1 I have 1 open problem / n I have 1 open problem

What I tried :

1. I made a table that aggregate by ID, then that gather the last value ( on timestamp ) of the status. It will show all problems and even the ones that are closed, but it's ok since I can say that my table is (now - 1min)  that way ( since closed problems don't send new logs ) I would only have the open problems.
   It kinda works but it is still not ideal since sometimes some open problems may still show for a minute
2. I tried TSVB, agg base metric, Lens Metric, runtime fields.
   None of them gave me what I wanted but maybe I just failed to deliver something that works and someone here can help me.

What kinda worked :

Vega)  I tried Vega as a last resort and I feel I can almost touch a solution ( even though I would love not to use Vega and find a way with the other types of metric )

Here is a request that gather all the problems and show the status

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "eventType.keyword": "problems"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "open_problems": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "problemId.keyword",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest_status": {
          "top_metrics": {
            "metrics": {
              "field": "problemStatus.keyword"
            },
            "size": 1,
            "sort": {
              "@timestamp": "desc"
            }
          }
        },
        "filtered_buckets": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "latestStatus": "latest_status"
            },
            "script": "params.latestStatus != 'close'"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I couldn't make bucket_selector to work even though : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/94967

I feel like the .keyword is breaking everything ?

So I tried to use  the request without the bucket_selector
It gives :

```
{
  "took": 801,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 10000,
      "relation": "gte"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "problems": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "id1",
          "doc_count": 17558,
          "latest_status": {
            "top": [
              {
                "sort": [
                  "2023-06-26T07:24:00.002Z"
                ],
                "metrics": {
                  "problemStatus.keyword": "open"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "id2",
          "doc_count": 17141,
          "latest_status": {
            "top": [
              {
                "sort": [
                  "2023-06-26T09:21:00.028Z"
                ],
                "metrics": {
                  "problemStatus.keyword": "close"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
```

So I wanted to use VEGA to make it work but I couldn't wrap my head around Vega ....

Vega :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "all_problems",
      "url": {
        "index": "myindex",
        "body": {
          "size": 0,
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "eventType.keyword": "problems"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "problems": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "problemId.keyword",
                "size": 10000
              },
              "aggs": {
                "latest_status": {
                  "top_metrics": {
                    "metrics": {
                      "field": "problemStatus.keyword"
                    },
                    "size": 1,
                    "sort": {
                      "@timestamp": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "format": {"property": "aggregations.problems.buckets"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
          "fill": {"value": "black"},
          "fontSize": {"value": 32}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"signal": "width / 2"},
          "y": {"signal": "height / 2"},
          "text": {"signal": "datum"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you help me find a solution ( Preferably without VEGA ) for my two problems ?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Please change the question tag to `Elasticsearch` , it attracts more viewers. Kibana it's just a Visualization Tool. Which is actually elastic dev tool.